# Can you tell me where the problem is in my html code?

Tags: python, html, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am currently following the Django tutorial from "Mozilla" the link is: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Forms#what_does_it_look_like
Here, the github with the code:
https://github.com/mdn/django-locallibrary-tutorial/blob/main/catalog/templates/catalog/bookinstance_list_borrowed_all.html

I'm stuck at this level: [The code I typed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiCz6.png) 
[The rendering I have on the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEqTS.png) 
[what should normally appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYHfg.png)
I have deleted the requested things but I still get the same kind of result. Can a kind soul help me to solve this problem?  Here are the different screenshots to better understand the situation. Thanks in advance.

Here the code I typed:
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}

## All Borrowed Books

```
{% if bookinstance_list %}
<ul>

  {% for bookinst in bookinstance_list %} 
  <li class="{% if bookinst.is_overdue %}text-danger{% endif %}">
    <a href="{% url 'book-detail' bookinst.book.pk %}">{{bookinst.book.title}}</a> ({{ bookinst.due_back }}) {% if user.is_staff %}- {{ bookinst.borrower }}{% endif %} {% if perms.catalog.can_mark_returned %}- <a href="{% url 'renew-book-librarian' bookinst.id %}">Renew</a>  {% endif %}
  </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>

{% else %}
  <p>There are no books borrowed.</p>
{% endif %}
```

{% endblock %}

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question . Note also that all the *relevant* code must be included in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Django template tags are not in-inline so it's raised in error but,

if you want to achieve no any borrowed book, then print the message `Borrowed book not found` you can achieve those things using `{% empty %}` tag like this...

```html
<ul>
  {% for bookinst in bookinstance_list %} 
  <li class="{% if bookinst.is_overdue %}text-danger{% endif %}">
    <a href="{% url 'book-detail' bookinst.book.pk %}">{{bookinst.book.title}}</a> ({{ bookinst.due_back }}) {% if user.is_staff %}- {{ bookinst.borrower }}{% endif %} {% if perms.catalog.can_mark_returned %}- <a href="{% url 'renew-book-librarian' bookinst.id %}">Renew</a>  {% endif %}
  </li>
  {% empty %}
  <li style="color: red;"> ----- There are no books borrowed. -----</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```